# How to detect that PWA is running from Google Play?

Tags: google-play, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I uploaded a PWA app (made with NuxtJS) to Google Play using pwabuilder.com to gain an additional source of traffic.

How can I identify users who are running the app from Google Play?

I found some information about the getInstalledRelatedApps() method, but I'm uncertain about it. It seems to promote the installation of the app from Google Play rather than the PWA. However, I'd prefer users to install the PWA version because it's more stable.